# TypeError: p.ɵɵelementStart(...) is not a function Upgrade from 12.2.0 to 14.2.7 angular

Tags: angular, angular14

Application successfully builds and ng serve runs. But when I start builded application - I have this exception:

I can't add image. The error is in second brackets.

```
p.\u0275\u0275elementStart(1, "div")(2, "button", 1),
```

I saw the same problem https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45265, but in my case all versions a same. I try reinstall all node_modules and have same result

error:

```
ERROR TypeError: p.ɵɵelementStart(...) is not a function
    at template (vlt.js?hash=0b1975a4496b70a3a7a5218fd430f5ea:1:3552527)
    at Ja (scripts.js:886:15814)
    at Ya (scripts.js:886:13798)
    at Iu (scripts.js:886:25408)
    at scripts.js:886:13997
    at Ya (scripts.js:886:14008)
    at t.create (scripts.js:1387:14596)
    at e.initializeComponent (scripts.js:2500:285)
    at scripts.js:2492:1779
    at e.runInZone (scripts.js:2500:2180)
```

ng version:

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.7
Node: 14.18.1
Package Manager: npm 6.14.15
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.2.7
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... elements, forms, localize, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.7
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.7
@schematics/angular             14.2.7
rxjs                            7.8.0
typescript                      4.6.4
```

I tried delete all node_modules and reinstall